# How do i create executable from spring maven project?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, executable-jar

I use Spring Tool Suite 4. We have a spring-boot API and we would like to create an  executable (jar or war, no clue, which one i need). We have dependencies stated in pom.xml. By default this is what we have under build if you make a clean spring-boot application:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

So my question what do i have to add so i can actually execute maven install for my executable? As of now if i run maven install (which for me the only way i know to create executable), it gives me an AssertionError. I tried to find guides online, but none of them worked.

For now i would be happy if i could even manage to execute maven install, but my plan includes the usage of config file outside of the executable also i would like to log (log4j2) next to the jar file, so i need help with those too. How to specify these in pom.xml so i can use config file from outside and to be able to log outside?

Comment: it seems you have a lot of issues before getting to execute your app from maven. Assuming you have solved them and you can do a successful mvn install a way to execute your app could be by doing :  mvn spring-boot:run

Comment: @Pitelk how about suggesting why do i get AssertionError? or suggest failiur points you know. Also program executed in Eclipse runs without error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got AssertionError, because for some reason some of my tests dont work for maven (even though if i execute them they pass). 
It actually matters if jar or war. In my case it has to be a war because im making an API
Also here are the minimum you have to change  in pom.xml to have a chance to create executable: (this goes before dependencies inside the pom.xml)

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
</properties>
```

The following part goes in between `<build></build>`.

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>your.main.class</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process-remote-resources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resourceBundles>
                                <resourceBundle>org.apache:apache-jar-resource-bundle:1.0</resourceBundle>
                            </resourceBundles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

To sum up I still have no idea what most of these do, but this works.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want an executable jar. Add this to your pom file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                <mainClass>
                  specify.your.main.Class
                </mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: will try tomorrow... Can you also answer other questions? such as how do i make lg4j2 to log outside of my executable?

Comment: you can do this in the configuration file of your log4j2

Comment: the question is how. Also how to do the same thing with config file(.ini)? @mahieus

Comment: Well i get Assertion error if i try your solution. What to do then?